# how to use collection of collection via using multimap (apache collection type)

Tags: jpa

How to use collection of collection via using multimap (apache collection type) .

I am using MultiMap but hibernate is not recognizing it as a collection type

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't understand commons collection types. You either can write your own custom UserType or provide get/set that returns the equivalent of Java Collections.